# How to view the http type (http, https) within a web page via chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to view the http type (http, https) within a web page via chrome browser?

I need to view whether for example all images of a given websites page are using http or https using chrome browser, any ideas?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach(img => console.log(img.src));`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery :

```
jQuery("body img").each(function(index, el) {
    var src = jQuery(this).attr('src');
    if (src.indexOf("https") >= 0){
        console.log('img in https');
    }else{
    console.log('not https');
  }
});
```

Comment: Change `>=` for `===`, because it would fail in an image like `<img src="http://www.examplehttpspage.com/myimage.jpg">`. Apart from that, why jQuery?